# Test run failed, Robotium

Tags: android, out-of-memory, robotium, ui-testing

I have a test for my Android application, and it's running without problems. But when I added `clickOnView` for one button it failed after clicking, Like:

```
Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError' bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Do you have any ideas why can this be happening? Should I create another AVD with bigger SD-card size? In the one I'm using I have 128MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OutOfMemoryError` has nothing to do with the AVM you created nor the SD-card you have set up.

The amount of memory used to handle your bitmaps is simple too big. You probably use bitmaps that are too big in dimension and/or too many of them.

You should check how you handle bitmaps in your application and/or test and see if you can improve them.

Useful reading: [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: So the problem is more in the app itself, then in my test?

Comment: Depends on your test. If you set up some heavy bitmaps there, it can't also cause the error but I think it is more likely that your app is the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I have not found the solution yet, but at least you've guided me to a right direction) Maybe you could advise me some tool to "check how you handle bitmaps in your application". In iOS I used UIAutomation for this...

Comment: Have you read the great article I have linked? You should check your code if you can improve it with the techniques given in the link...

Comment: I'm only testing the app, it's not my code) That's why I had to know where the problem is and who should take care of it - me or the developers)

Answer (score 0):

Please goto your project properties-->java build path
hit on order and Export tab
mark 1.yourProject/src
     2.yourProject/gen
hit on libraries
make sure acra file in list
hit on ok
then clean your project..
and run it..

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the solution, maybe it's gonna be useful for somebody. In my AVD properties I've changed the Max VM application heap size to 64 (it used to be 24), and the problem is gone.